# ADB not running or starting

Tags: android, adb

When I try to start adb using the "adb start-server" command, the command line doesn't respond, and adb shows up for a second in the task manager, but then disappears. I've tried re installing, and a fresh copy of the SDK has the problem. When I type in "adb devices", the output is: "error: protocol fault (no status)" Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Also, when I update the SDK, I get this code: Starting ADB server failed (code -1).

[image]

Comment: Try asking on the android google group. You are more likely to get help there.

Comment: Where is that located?

Comment: Are you sure that you are writing the adb commands at android sdk's adb installation path?

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure. I attached a screenshot.

Comment: @ElectronicGeek: Here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-developers

Comment: I posted a q there, but I'd be very grateful if there's any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my parental control software was interfering with adb.

Comment: Can you give an explained solution how to fix it, because I am also getting the same problem of yours.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server` again.

After that, `adb devices` should work correctly.

Comment: Ive done that. When i do adb kill-server it says that adb was never running.

Comment: I found this on xda-developers: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1011355. Perhaps give that a try? I've had problems with ADB on Windows too, where I'd have to restart it

Comment: The problem for me is that adb doesn't even start.

Comment: Nevermind, I found out it was a problem with a parental controls software disallowing adb from running.